# How to add an element into the vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have this:

> `std::vector <BinaryTree*> children;`

where `BinaryTree` is a class. How can I add an element into this vector?

I tried `children.push_back(X)` where `X` is an instance of the class but it gives me this error:

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BinaryTree' to 'BinaryTree *&&'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the `push_back()` and pass a *pointer* to an instance of `BinaryTree`:

```
std::vector <BinaryTree*> children;
BinaryTree* pTree = new BinaryTree();
children.push_back(pTree);
...
delete pTree;
```

In order to avoid manual memory management, if you need reference semantics, use smart pointers instead of raw pointers:

```
#include <memory> // For std::shared_ptr

std::vector <std::shared_ptr<BinaryTree>> children;
std::shared_ptr<BinaryTree> pTree = std::make_shared<BinaryTree>();
children.push_back(pTree);
...
// No need to delete pTree
```

The `std::shared_ptr<>` class template is part of the C++11 Standard Library. In C++03, you could use the (almost) equivalent `boost::shared_ptr<>`:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> // For std::shared_ptr

std::vector <boost::shared_ptr<BinaryTree>> children;
boost::shared_ptr<BinaryTree> pTree = boost::make_shared<BinaryTree>();
children.push_back(pTree);
...
// No need to delete pTree
```

Finally, if you do not need reference semantics at all and want to treat your binary trees as values instead, you can even consider defining a `std::vector<BinaryTree>`:

```
std::vector<BinaryTree> children;
BinaryTree tree;
children.push_back(tree);
```

Comment: Worth to note that `std::shared_ptr` is C++11 feature.

Comment: @LihO Not really, `shared_ptr` is available under C++03 as `std::tr1::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 3):

Omit the asterisk `*` from the template argument:

```
std::vector<BinaryTree> children;
```

You want children to hold the data, without manual/dynamic memory allocation as in `new BinaryTree`.

Comment: You **definitely** don't want to do this. the right way is to keep pointers in the container.

Comment: @Cthulhu, thanks for your edit, I wrote "asterix" for years. As Wikipedia says: "Not to be confused with Asterix." :-)

Comment: @arrows `template <class T> struct BinaryTree { T value; BinaryTree *left, *right; }`?

Comment: @juanchopanza it won't be funny any more when you actually implement it, just try it.

Comment: @arrows we don't know anything about `BinaryTree`, and can only guess the role of this vector.

Comment: alright, now we don't know what a binary tree is... you see, it's not funny at all.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on who is supposed to own the pointers. In the simplest case, where the vector doesn't own them, then you pass the address of a `BinaryTree` object.

```
BinaryTree b = ...;
children.push_back(&b);
```

But you have to be sure `b` lives at least as long as `children` does.

If the vector owns the pointers, then you should probably store smart pointers to avoid having to deal with memory managemen:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BinaryTree>> children;
children.push_back(std::unique_ptr<BinaryTree>(new BinaryTree(args)));
```

If you don't know what all this "ownership" business means, then you are most likely better off with a plain vector of objects:

```
std::vector<BinaryTree> children;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<SomeObject*> objectVector;
objectVector.push_back(new SomeObject());
```

Is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have vector of pointers:

```
std::vector <BinaryTree*> children;
```

so the proper way of adding elements is:

```
BinaryTree* child = new BinaryTree();
children.push_back(child);
```

just be careful while doing something like this:

```
{
    BinaryTree child;
    children.push_back(&child);
}
```

because lifetime of such an element might be shorter than lifetime of the vector and you might end up trying to access an element that no longer exists (dangling pointer) which produces *undefined behavior*. Also don't forget to `delete` these elements when done with it.

But it's always good to consider using vector of objects first  (i.e.`std::vector<BinaryTree>`) since that would take care of that ugly memory management for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
children.push_back(&X);
```

This will work but bear in mind that once your object leaves scope, its deleter will be called and you will be left with an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
children.push_back(&X);
```

Pass the address as if you were using it as a pointer. But the problem then is if that instance goes out of scope, so better to do this

```
BinaryTree* X = new BinaryTree;
children.push_back(X);
```

This will ensure that X never goes out of scope, but then you have to manually delete it when you're finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

The `vector` contains *pointers to* objects of type `BinaryTree`. You need

```
BinaryTree bt;
children.push_back( &bt );
```

But you must ensure that the lifetime of the `bt` object at least matches that of the `vector`.

You may want this instead

```
children.push_back( new BinaryTree );
```

But in this case you must call `delete` on the pointer contained in the `vector` to prevent a memory leak.

As evident, neither option is easy to manage. An easy change is to make your container store the elements by value.

```
std::vector<BinaryTree> children;
BinaryTree bt;
children.push_back( bt );
```

If you must store pointers, use a smart pointer to hold them instead.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BinaryTree>> children;
children.push_back( new BinaryTree );
```

Now you don't need to worry about deleting the objects before emptying the vector.